# WinCe 6.0 add ActiveSync to image

Tags: windows-ce

i'm new im WinCe develop. I create image for device and upload and install it on device. All setup Ok and OS load. But I didn't found Activesync on device. after connect device to PC nothig happans. activesync not connected. I've cheack ActiveSync option on Catalog item window.So CoreOs->CEBASE->ApplicationsEndUse-ActiveSync.
Maybe I must add something else?

Answer (score 1):

The required and relative components are:

1. Core OS->Applications - End User->ActiveSync->File Sync
2. Core OS->Communication Services and Networking->Networking - Wide Area Network (WAN)->Dial Up Networking (RAS/PPP)
3. Core OS->Communication Services and Networking->Networking - Wide Area Network (WAN)->Telephony API (TAPI 2.0)->Unimodem Support
4. Core OS->Shell and User Interface->User Interface->Network User Interface